# POST Response of Laravel 5 just triggers complete but not success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i played around with Laravel 5 and i just tried to send POST to my controller.
all seems to work but the success ajax method is not called. Instead the complete method is triggered. the header status is 200 and no error occurs.

Here is my load function:

```
load: function() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: 'index.php/profile/sayings',
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {'_token': $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        complete: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Routing:

```
Route::post('profile/sayings', 'ProfileController@sayings');
```

Controller:

```
public function sayings() {

    return Response::json($this->docHelper->getSayings(), 200);
}
```

request header:

```
    POST /profile_dyn/laravel/index.php/profile/sayings HTTP/1.1
    Host: 192.168.1.104
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 47
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Origin: http://192.168.1.104
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    Referer: http://192.168.1.104/profile_dyn/laravel/
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
    Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjNBQUVHeFZcL0RaY21vNWQ0RHdiQ3RBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkY1MHR2K2ZLdnQxMzFkK2cxSFwvQ1pqZEVFYnNBaWdvZ05WQTJuSmF6ZU9jQ295WGpRSnFpaTZVZnMwYit0XC8xMGtWYm1leTQ2SGw3QXlzMUJxdWxcL01BPT0iLCJtYWMiOiJkYTVkMjUzMzJjNGRhMGIwNTY0YzJlY2FjNjhhMzFmNDQ5ZWQ3MGNkMTY0ZDNjZDM1OWQ5MzBkMWY4YTYzZjU5In0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InZQdk40M05mbXpWQXFVdENuK3l5bHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiM0ZiYWhoN1Fmd3FjZWlCcU1yT1JYbjVNZkJDbmtPbFgxa2ZyRENBd2ptYzhMdU01UVBSdHRjUUtjMzE4M1VcL0h6aEtoYkFxTzdHb0pCbTJWdHhpZWt3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiIyZmVjZTY2NzFhNDZiNWRjYTQ2MWMwYTg4NjM1YzQ1YjQ0YWZjZDA0MmQ2Nzc1MGU4ZTk0MjVkZjA2NjZjNDljIn0%3D
    X-FirePHP: 0.4.4
    X-FirePHP-Version: 0.4.4
    X-Wf-Max-Combined-Size: 262144
```

response header:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Sat, 19 Sep 2015 19:58:01 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjhsdjVxbUtcL1RTR2p0N1JjeE5UTXd3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Imt6TDdKd1M5UFwvUVlraTNXZDQrUkJXOFNCWjNpdURCR0gwMkRza3NIazZSM2pQVUxoMzlmd2EzRDB2cUMrVU51ajFibUduaVMzcEt3OFNKSnN6Ukhsdz09IiwibWFjIjoiOTY4YWUwMWZiMjU4YWI2OGExNmY2NTAwMzc0N2RmMzNiNDY4YWVlZDU3NDQzMmM5ZjI1MmU3ZTA0NTlkNDU2YyJ9; expires=Sat, 19-Sep-2015 21:58:01 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
    Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InVQQkNlM0FDMGYyNVliS1pvZUQ4RkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiS3ZjbmRrNFRzQjRCRXNLQnFvVHBicHhhVGQ4cjRKR0pcL085aXJKc3A5bmZZZmh1SFNmQTRZeVZxUktYdVhUcDVwaGRHOG1SR0N2RTBUd1ZtSUlXSnh3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiIzOTkyZTRkOWJlZjllZWFkN2I3YjM4M2EzZWNjZWE3YjEwNzYzNGExYjEwNzdlYmMyODNlMmFhODU1ODkwYTI5In0%3D; expires=Sat, 19-Sep-2015 21:58:01 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
    Content-Length: 3906
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=94
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Type: application/json
```

Just the complete function fires with status 200, statusText ok, readyState 4 and a valid responseText.

If the http header is not 200, complete would be fine. I do not know any reason for not firing success in this case. Probably one of you could explain this behaviour.

Cheers

Comment: Could you please post the response headers?

Comment: added headers to first post

Comment: Headers seem to be ok. Try using `done` instead of `success`. I know `success` has been deprecated for some time, and maybe it was removed in the jQuery version you're using (just guessing here).

Comment: `done` doesnt work neither. I'm using jQuery 2.14

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? On all my tests the code you have posted works.

Comment: Everything looks good to me too. Maybe try to simplify the JS side? Try making requests from the console instead of a script in your page to see if something else is interfering. You might want to disable the CSRF filter in Laravel for these tests.

Comment: `curl -X POST http://192.168.1.104/profile_dyn/laravel/index.php/profile/sayings` delivered the JSOn string which i aspected. There was no error at all. I guess it must be a a jQuery Problem. I will try out another jQuery version when i arrived at home

Comment: i tried oit jQuery 1.9.1 and 1.11.3. Both versions just trigger `complete`